# initializing different values of map in different locations in golang

Tags: go, struct

I'm creating a map of structs to hold different information. A sample struct I am using is:

```
type Test struct{
  Value1 string
  Value2 string
  Value3 string
  Value4 string
}

func main() {
  testMap := make(map[string]*Test) //using a pointer to map
  func2(testMap)
  //pass map to another function for more additions.
}

func func2 (testMap map[string]*Test) {
  a, b := getVal(); //get some random values
  res := concat(a,b) //basically create a string key based on values a and b
  testMap[res].value1 = a   //****
  testMap[res].value2 = b
  //do something else
  testMap[res].value3 = "hello"

}
```

I'm basically trying to create a map and add values to it as I get them, but im getting a `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` error on **** line (see code for ***).

Comment: That means that `testMap[res]` is `nil`. As the error says, you can't dereference (eg access fields of) a `nil` pointer.

Comment: that makes sense.. so how do I create an entry for map.. without knowing all the fields? (apart from getting all the fields and creating it in the end with all the values)

Comment: `testMap[res] = &Test{}` would insert a new empty instance, is that what you mean? Have you taken the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org)?

Comment: That was it. Thank you. For some reason I missed that in the tour. I did recall it doing it by value and not through pointers, which is what confused me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
func func2 (testMap map[string]*Test) {
  a, b := getVal(); //get some random values
  res := concat(a,b) //basically create a string key based on values a and b
  testMap[res] = &Test{
     Value1: a,
     Value2: b,
     Value3: "string",
  }

}
```

Or if you want to create the object first, then populate the value, try

```
func func2 (testMap map[string]*Test) {
  a, b := getVal(); //get some random values
  res := concat(a,b) //basically create a string key based on values a and b
  testMap[res] = &Test{}
  testMap[res].value1 = a   //****
  testMap[res].value2 = b
  //do something else
  testMap[res].value3 = "hello"

}
```